# How to copy from VSCode into outlook without format

Tags: visual-studio-code, outlook, copy-paste

When I copy from VSCode into the email in outlook, by default the format was copied together. Quite often it is not what I want. For example I just wanted to quote a function name or variable name into a sentence. But after I pasted it, the format of the whole paragraph was changed. Is there any convenient way that we just copy the text only. Or even better, limit the format only applied to the copied text instead polluting the other part of the paragraph?

Comment: is there not a function outlook to paste without formatting or change how the formatting is applied after pasting?